# error occured when compiling linux kernel

Tags: compiler-errors, linux-kernel, compilation

Just got this error when compiling kernels. I have done search about this error but few infos were got. Can someone help?

```
fs/jffs2/xattr.c: In function ‘jffs2_build_xattr_subsystem’:
fs/jffs2/xattr.c:887:1: warning: the frame size of 1152 bytes is larger than 1024 bytes [-Wframe-larger-than=]
  887 | }
      | ^
```

and this at the end of the compilation:

```
make: *** [Makefile:2021：.] error 2
```

I tried googled it but there nearly no helpful things back, and I have re-run the make procedure but it just happened the same.

Comment: On which **distro** do you build the kernel? Which kernel version do you use? How do you configured it?

Comment: I guess you could either configure the kernel with CONFIG_WERROR not set (so that warnings are not turned into errors), or configure the kernel with a larger value for CONFIG_FRAME_WARN.

Comment: `xref_tmphash` is an auto array of 128 pointers. Normally the kernel limits stack by dynamic allocation of such arrays. This routine violates normal style.

Comment: thank you guys for your reply, i solved that issue few days ago with restoring my machine and re-compiled without problems, it seems like its some kinds of unknown or not common issue, and i used defconfig all the time, thanks again and best wishes guys